# device size Bootstrap CSS Content cross the wrap line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i thought my div tags has no match with other but i check again and again it is not. it's something strange with this. i can't understand why the content went everywhere and i got whitegaps at top after navigation and right after content.

this is what i got
[image: the yellow wrap should be all over the content]
[image: White Gaps between nav and right panel]

for the yellow wrap i tried to using

```
margin:0; padding:0;height:100%; width:100%;
```

but it doesn't work.

for the gaps i tried using `overflow: hidden`
it work, but it's not perfect for my navigation. the width still overflowing but i can't see the corner(mean just hidden it).

btw im using bootstrap and tried to modified some of em. it work just fine at desktop size any desktop. but when i turned out into mobile device (iPhone 5 orientation: potrait) it went wrong.

please help, i don't know what's happened. as far as i know
     `margin:0; padding:0;height:100%; width:100%;` are the magic trick. but is not.

```css
/* About Us */
#aboutus{
 position:relative;
 background:#ffff00;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
.aboutus{
 position:relative;
 margin-top:80px;
 height:auto}
.aboutus > h1 {
 padding:0 5%;
 letter-spacing:5px;
}
.aboutusleft, .aboutusright{
 height:auto;
 padding:0 5% 0% 5%;
}
.aboutus h2{
 letter-spacing:4px;
 padding:5% 5% 1% 5%;}
.aboutus h3{
 letter-spacing:1px;
 line-height:1.5;
}
.aboutus h3:first-child{
 position:relative;
 margin-bottom:100px;
 z-index:90;
} 
.aboutuspitch{
 position:absolute;
 right:2%;
 top:100%;
 text-align:right;
 width:50%;
 transform:translate(-2%, -50%);
 z-index:88;
}
.aboutuspitch img{
  width:80%;
}
.ourteam{
 background:url(../touchupAssets/about/Background1.png);
 background-size:100% 100%;
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
 }
.ourteamContent img{
 width:100%;
}
.ourteamContent > h1{
 letter-spacing:8px;
}

#ourteamRight{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 right:0;
 padding-right:5%;
 padding-left:0;
 transform:translate(0,-50%);
 line-height:1.5;
 letter-spacing:2px;
}
.profileBack:first-child{
 background:none;
}
#wrapProfileBack{
 margin-top:-20%;
}
.psycholog{
 padding:0;
 margin-top:-2%;
 min-height:50vh;
 }
.abouttitle{
 padding:25px 100px;
 letter-spacing:5px;
 }
.associates{
 margin-top:-2%;
 padding-bottom:5%;
 background:url(../assets/BG_3.png);
 background-size:100% 100%;
 min-height:50vh; 
 }

.profile{
 height:100%;
 width:75%;
 position:relative;
 left:50%;
 transform:translateX(-50%);
}

.profilecontent{
 padding:5% 0;
 width:75%;
 float:none;
 position:relative;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.profilepict, .profiletext{
   }
.profiletext{
 padding:0;
}
.profiletext > h2 {
 letter-spacing:5px;
}
.psytitle{
 margin-bottom:50px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.profiletext > h3{
 padding-right:15%;
 letter-spacing:2px;
 line-height:1.5;
 font-size:21px;
}
.profilepict{
 margin-top:-15%;
 display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:flex-start;
 align-self:flex-start;
 padding:0;
}
.profilepict img{
    width:150%;
  height:100%;
}

.profileBack:nth-child(odd){
 position:relative;
 z-index:22;
 margin-top:-8%;
 max-height:100%;
}
.profileBack:nth-child(even){
 position:relative;
 margin-top:-8%;
 max-height:100%;
 z-index:20;
}
.profileBack:nth-child(odd):nth-child(3n+1){
background:url(../touchupAssets/about/CyanBackground.png);
 background-size:100% 100%;
 }
.profileBack:nth-child(even):nth-child(3n+2){
 background:#f61a7c;
 background-size:100% 100%;
 }
.profileBack:nth-child(odd):nth-child(3n+3){
background:url(../touchupAssets/about/YellowBackground.png);
 background-size:100% 100%;
 }
.profileBack:nth-child(even):nth-child(3n+4){
 background:#99ffff;
 background-size:100% 100%;
 }
.profileBack:nth-child(odd):nth-child(3n+5){
background:url(../touchupAssets/about/MagentaBackground.png);
 background-size:100% 100%;
 }
.profileBack:nth-child(even):nth-child(3n+6){
 background:#ffff00;
 background-size:100% 100%;
 } 

div.profileBack:nth-child(odd) .profiletext {
 float:right;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 display:flex;
 height:100%;
 align-items:flex-start;
 justify-content:center;
 flex-direction:column;
   }
div.profileBack:nth-child(odd) .profilepict {
 float:right;
 padding:0;
 margin-top:0;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left0;
 display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:flex-start;
 align-self:flex-start;
}
div.profileBack:nth-child(odd) .profiletext >h2{
 padding-left:20%;
}   
div.profileBack:nth-child(odd) .profiletext >h3{
 padding-left:20%;
 padding-right:0;
}

div.profileBack:nth-child(even) .profiletext{
 float:left;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:flex;
 height:100%;
 align-items:flex-start;
 justify-content:center;
 flex-direction:column;

}
div.profileBack:nth-child(even) .profilepict{
 float:left;
 padding:0;
 margin-top:0;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 position:absolute;
 display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:flex-start;
 align-self:flex-start;
}
.devteam{
 position:relative;
 z-index:21;
 background:#fff;
 background-size:100% 100%;
 min-height:100%;
 margin-top:-8%;
 padding-top:8%;
 text-align:center;
 }
 
.teamimg{
 height:50%;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 }
.teamimgdmg img{
 width:100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 773px) {
/*About Us*/
#aboutus{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
  .aboutus{
  margin-top:50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'core/function/profile.php';

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>About Us</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/navigation.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/laptop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/mobile.css">

</head>
<body>

            <header class="navigation nav-down">
<nav class="clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 navHome"><a href="index.php"><img src="assets/logo_PG.png" /></a></li>
      <li id="currentnav" class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><a href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><a href="ourservices.php">OUR SERVICES</a></li>
  <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><a href="journals.php">EVENTS</a></li>
  <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><a href="articles.php">ARTICLES</a></li>
      <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><a href="news.php">NEWS</a></li>
      <li class="col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><a href="contactus.php">CONTACT US</a></li>  
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="pull">text</a>
</nav>
            </header>
            
      <div id="aboutus">
        <div class="aboutus row">
<h1>ABOUT US</h1><br>
            
<div class="aboutusleft col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<h3>
text</h3>
</div>
<div class="aboutusright col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<h3>
text</h3></div>

  <div class="aboutuspitch">
   <img src="touchupAssets/about/tagline.png">
 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ourteam row">
<div id="ourteamLeft" class="ourteamContent col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
 <img src="touchupAssets/about/PhotoTeam.png">
</div>
<div id="ourteamRight" class="ourteamContent col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12"><h3>
text</h3>
</div>
 </div>
  <div class="psycholog container-fluid">
 <div class="abouttitle row">
      <h1> PYSCHOLOGISTS</h1>
  </div>
 <div class="profilecontent container">
<div class="row asd">  
<div class="profiletext col-xs-8">text</div>
<div class="profilepict col-xs-4">     <img src="images/profilePicture/iBuRatih.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapProfileBack">     
<?php
while($profile = mysql_fetch_array($psychologQuery)){
?>                  
<div class="row profileBack">  
    <div class="row profile">
    <div class="profiletext col-xs-8">
 <h2><?php echo $profile['psycholog_name']?></h2>   <h3><?php echo $profile['psycholog_title'];?></h3>
<h2><?php echo $profile['specialist']?></h2>
<h3><?php echo $profile['displayDescription'];?></h3>
 </div>         
<div class="profilepict col-xs-4 ">
<img src="images/profilePicture/<?php  echo $profile['image'];?>">
   </div>
 <span style="clear:both"></span>
        </div>
</div>   
<?php
}
?>

</div>
                    
            </div>

            <div class="devteam row">
              <div class="abouttitle row">
                    <h1>
                    DEVELOPMENT TEAM
                    </h1>
                </div>
     <div class="row teamimg">
      <div class="col-xs-2 teamimgdmg"><img src="touchupAssets/about/Account.png"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 teamimgdmg"><img src="touchupAssets/about/Content.png"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 teamimgdmg"><img src="touchupAssets/about/Creative.png"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 teamimgdmg"><img src="touchupAssets/about/Media.png"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 teamimgdmg"><img src="touchupAssets/about/Research.png"></div>
     </div>
      </div>      
<div style="clear:both"></div>      
</div>    
</body>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="style/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- custom -->
     <script src="style/navigation.js"></script>
  
</html>
```

Comment: where your html ?

Comment: @LaljiTadhani i will upload the fiddle, one sec.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani can u check that? sorry, a bit messy

Comment: can you please remove margin-top:80px form .about use class. And let me now if white space gone or not between nav and about-us .

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Sorry for the late reply, i forgot to put margin-top:50px at .aboutus mobile.css.. ya indeed whitegaps after navigation has disappearing from the view. but it doesn't change for the wrap size. thx for ur contribution.

Comment: Its ok . sounds good you have one problem solved. I don't  get the wrap issue with snippet. I will try my best to solve that issue. I will give a suggestion after all you are using bootstrap so you can put <img class="img-responsive" src=" demo.png"/> 
its a bootstrap default class.

Comment: it's all solved. thx to u mostafa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got my answer thx to @MostafaBaezid to give me a little clue.

this is what i did in mobile.css

```
#aboutus{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow-X:hidden;
}
.aboutus{
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

and it change everything to be in place. but hard to believe tho. it just an overflow and a margin-top. it silly to made div#aboutus 100% width and height, but it works.